# How to remove background colour when long pressed on a row for second time in custom GridView ? (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, onlongclicklistener

I have a custom GridView with an ImageView and TextView in it. I want to colour a particular row when long press on it and to remove the background colour when long press the next time. Previously I asked a question of this type- [How to unselect an item in gridview on second click in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834273/how-to-unselect-an-item-in-gridview-on-second-click-in-android), so I referred it. But I can't apply that solution in this case-

```
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
            longPressed();
            return true;
        }
});
```

How this code should be edited to give background colour and transparent colour on alternative long clicks ?

Comment: whats wrong with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834273/how-to-unselect-an-item-in-gridview-on-second-click-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834273/how-to-unselect-an-item-in-gridview-on-second-click-in-android) answer ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal The remove statement in if condition generates error when I tried to implement that code here.

Comment: can you post the code which statement is generating error?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I will describe rather. onItemLongClick() has boolean as return type and onItemClick() has void as return type. So when the return statement is used, it causes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

1.- Add a var to keep track which background colour is going to be set next. For example a boolean could do the job:

boolean backgroundColorTransparent = false;

Then use it in your code to trigger the corresponding code and make sure you update the var for next long press click.

gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(backgroundColorTransparent){

        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        longPressed();
        backgroundColorTransparent = false;

        }else{

        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
        longPressed();
        backgroundColorTransparent = true;

    }
    return true;
```

});

Answer (score 3):

in your code use one flag variable that represent the no. of times u clicked on the item.

on first click set the background to normal and on the next click set the background to the color u want.

take one globle color variable as

```
Color COLOR = Color.rgb(128, 128, 128);
boolean flag = false;
```

change your code from.

```
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
        longPressed();
        return true;
    }
});
```

to

```
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        flag = !flag;

        if(flag==true)
        {
          arg1.setBackgroundColor(COLOR);
          COLOR = color.background_light;

        }
        else
        {
           arg1.setBackgroundColor(COLOR);
         COLOR = Color.rgb(128, 128, 128);
        }
        longPressed();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Here you have to do something that the if condition should be checked for every item in the grid view individually.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can set a unique tag for the views, you could keep a List of id's for clicked views :

```
// This will be a member variable of your Activity/Fragment, 
// holding tags of the clicked views
List<Object> clickedTags = new ArrayList<>();

gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        if (clickedTags.contains(args1.getTag())){
            // The view was clicked, remove tag from list and handle event
            clickedTags.remove(args1.getTag());
            // set transparent background and anything you need to do
            args1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            return true;
        } else {
            clickedTags.add(args1.getTag());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));
            longPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where should I have to implement this code ? Also where is gv(object of GridView), which was in my code ?

Comment: Declare the list as a member of your class (probably a Fragment or Activity, right) and if you pay attention, I just removed the gv for clarity, but I'll edit my question so it's clearer for you.

Comment: It still needs some major editing. Your code gives background colour on 1st click and is not removing it on the next click.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            boolean isSelected = (arg1.getTag() == null) ? false : (Boolean) arg1.getTag();

            if(isSelected){
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //your unselected color here.
            } else {
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //your selected color here.
            }

            arg1.setTag(!isSelected);

            longPressed();
            return true;
        }
```